# Localise Application for English and Arabic Language without restarting app

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to localise application for two languages one is LTR & Another is RTL without restarting application.

```
class func changeLanguageForceFully(currLan : String){
        let langCultureCode: String = currLan
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject([langCultureCode], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
```

Above function is working fine but it takes effect after restarting the application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you supporting Arabic internationalisation in your project info?

[image]

Also are you setting constraints using leading/trailing?

Comment: Are you supporting Arabic internationalisation in your project info? ==> not clear , i have to add something in info.plist ?

Comment: You may want to add Arabic to the Localizations. Also, what type of TextAlignement do you use for the Labels? You should use NSTextAlignment.natural